# I am getting error filtering template: Notice: Undefine Variable :imageBlockBuilder

Tags: magento-2.1.7

I am using Porto theme.I am getting error like

> Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined variable:
>   imageBlockBuilder

In my home page.

Comment: To avoid this Notice you can add at symbol in-front of imageBlockBuilder ( @$this->imageBlockBuilder / imageBlockBuilder ). If you share your code I will try to provide proper fix.